# How to customize pie chart using MPAndroidChart in Android?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

**What I have done:** I'm using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I was able to customize it to my requirement and tried further functionalities to remove Description Label, and to increase the font and customize the legend. What I have is now ;

[image]

```
 <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            >

        </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
```

public class PFrag extends Fragment {

```
    float time[] = {55, 95, 30 , 360 - (55+95+30)};
    String activity[] ={"Jan","Feb","March",""};
    PieChart pieChart;
    CircularProgressIndicator circularProgress;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.panorama_frag,container,false);

       pieChart = view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        setupPieChart();

        //circularProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.circular_progress);
       // circularProgress.setMaxProgress(10000);
      //  circularProgress.setCurrentProgress(5000);

        return view;
    }

    private void setupPieChart(){

        //pupulating list of PieEntires
        List<PieEntry> pieEntires = new ArrayList<>();
        for( int i = 0 ; i<time.length;i++){
            pieEntires.add(new PieEntry(time[i],activity[i]));
        }
        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntires,"");
        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        //Get the chart
        pieChart.setData(data);
        pieChart.invalidate();
        pieChart.setCenterText("50% \n ");
        pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
        pieChart.setContentDescription("");
        //pieChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
        //pieChart.setMaxHighlightDistance(34);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12);
        pieChart.setHoleRadius(75);

        //legend attributes
        Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
        legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
        legend.setTextSize(12);
        legend.setFormSize(20);
        legend.setFormToTextSpace(2);


    }

}
```

**What I'm looking for:** Though I tried it seems unable to find a way to edit the below functionalities.

- How to remove the "Description Label" in the right-left corner?
- How to increase the text size of the chart?
- How to remove the blue item from the legend so that it will be the default remaining value?

Simply what I'm looking for is a graph like below.
[image]

To achieve that I used MPAndoridChart library after some searching and stuck here. I'm using Android Studio 3.6.1. I would really appreciate any suggestion on this.

Thank you!

---

**I was able to solve below two queries:**

- How to remove the "Description Label" in the right-left corner

  ```
  pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
  ```
- How to increase the text size of the chart? > add

  ```
  data.setValueTextSize(10);
  ```

Comment: I don't think you can hide that item without a custom renderer. Also, if your goal is to achieve a chart like the one presented in the screenshot, I think you're better off doing it yourself without mpandroidchart, otherwise it will be too inconvenient.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you for the suggestion. I see, I got your point. I'm new to Android Studio yet, may I know what are the options available for me to do it myself? When I search suggestions were this library and I choose it first.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's neither easy nor simple, especially if you're just beginning. My suggestion for you would be to keep using mpandroidchart but aim for a simpler UI. For example instead of hiding the item you could label it "Calories to goal" or something.

Comment: I see, thank you for the suggestions. Maybe  I want to think of changing my design.

Comment: Maybe it can help you. [DecoView](https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting)

Comment: Thank you @KasımÖzdemir, let me try.

Answer (score 2):

To remove label inside data just use

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(false)
```